# Numerical scheme for $ \int_{S^2} f(x) \, dS \approx \sum_P f(P) $

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, na.numerical-analysis

The midpoint rule or trapezoid rule is only good up to an error, for some $c \in [a,b]$ we have that:

$$ \left| \int_a^b f(x) \, dx - \frac{1}{2}\big[\,f(b)+f(a)\,\big](b-a)\right| < \frac{1}{12}\,f''(c)$$

this estimate can be found in an numerical analysis textbook. I propose the following integration scheme:

$$ \int_{S^2} f(x) \, dS \approx \sum_P f(P) $$

where $P$ represents a set of points on the sphere.  Based on the equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 5$.

$$P = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}  \Big\{  \big( 0,\pm 1,\pm2  \big),
\dots 
 \Big\} $$

Can we get an estimate for how well this sum over $P$ approximates the integral?

$$ \Bigg|\int_{S^2} f(x) \, dS - \sum_P f(P) \Bigg| <  C \cdot \max_{\xi \in S^2}|\xi^T H(0) \xi|$$
In particular, what is the best constant $C$ that can be placed there?
$$ f(x+\Delta x) = f(\Delta x)  + \nabla f(x)^T\, \Delta x + \tfrac{1}{2} \Delta x^T H(x) \Delta x $$
where $H(x)$ is the [Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix) matrix of all possible second derivatives $\partial_i \partial_j\,  f(x)$.

---

*Comment #1* Who knows what the correct error term should be?  I would just try the maxmum value of all partial derivatives:

$$ \max_{\xi \in S^2} \Bigg\{ \bigg| \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\, \partial y}\bigg|,
\bigg|\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\, \partial z}\bigg|,
\bigg|\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\, \partial z}\bigg|,
 \; \bigg| \frac{\partial^2 f}{ \partial x^2}\bigg| , 
 \; \bigg| \frac{\partial^2 f}{ \partial y^2}\bigg| ,
 \; \bigg| \frac{\partial^2 f}{ \partial z^2}\bigg|   \Bigg\} $$

and this is not particularly refined.  I was going to say $f \in L^2(S^2)$ but those are not necessarily smooth.  If I say $f \in C^\infty(S^2)$ those are certainly not all in $L^2$.  Just say polynomials in $x,y,z$ of arbitrary degree  Or perhaps even with differentiability assumption $C^1$ or $C^2$ or etc.

Mostly I am just thinking in analogy with 1-dimensional case.  Locally this is product of 1 dimensional case.  We could integrate over the two hemispheres and use spherical coordinates or whatever and obtain a bound.

I am using $6 \times 4 = 24 $ points I believe this is some kind of snub-cube.  <del>I am drawing it right now.</del>

[image]

---

*Comment #2* Over $\mathbb{R}$ there are many careful discussions of numerical integration (and integrating differential equations, so instead of $D = \frac{d}{dx}$ we can have more complicated operator, such as Sturm-Liouville or Riemann-Hilbert or Euler's method or whatever you like).

Over manifolds I definitely do **not** see a lot of discretization schemes.  Perhaps because space is curve or a topological space but mainly we are trying to approximate continuous sum with discrete sum.  Here I'm interested approximating discrete sum with continuous integral.

I am asking about this particular integration scheme and **any** way to approximate the error.  Intuitively the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) says the error should be proportional to second derivatives at various points, if I assume certain regular behavior.

Comment: Why just $x$ and $y$ on the right side?  The left side won't necessarily be zero if $f$ just depends on $z$.  Also you'll want to normalize the terms on the left properly so that you get $0$ for constant $f$.

Comment: The error term definitely cannot be presented in this form: you can find a lot of functions (e.g. high order polynomials) with $H(0)=0$  but nonzero error.